# What is the equivalent of POSIX's group ID on Windows?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, process, psapi

When analyzing the process tree in C++, POSIX allows you to prune it using group ID. Several processes may be added to a particular group.

Eg. see the following POSIX function.

[add my process to a group](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/setpgrp.html)

Does Windows have an equivalent of the above?
I would like to assign a bunch of processes I own to a group, and then control the group as a whole.

Eg.

[kill all processes in my group](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/kill.html)

Comment: Perhaps https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/procthread/processor-groups ?

Comment: @SeverinPappadeux - "Processor Groups" is not the same thing as "Process Groups".  The former is about managing scheduling on CPU cores. Not the same thing as what the OP is asking about.

Comment: Why must Windows have the equivalent? Moreover, as @Artyer answered, [Job objects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/procthread/job-objects) have the same function.

Answer (score 2):

Windows has [process groups](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-process-groups) which each newly created child process is added to unless it is created with the [`CREATE_NEW_PROCESS_GROUP`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/procthread/process-creation-flags) flag. This is only useful for the [`GenerateConsoleCtrlEvent`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/generateconsolectrlevent) function as far as I know.

[Job objects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/procthread/job-objects) might be more useful to you. For example, you can kill all process associated with a given job with [`TerminateJobObject`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/jobapi2/nf-jobapi2-terminatejobobject).